# PyKeyboard.tap_key() doesn't work when I disconnect from Remote Desktop

Tags: python, windows, winapi, remote-desktop

I have a program that uses PyKeyboard.tap_key() to send keystrokes to another application that I'm automating (the application can't be automated any other way, unfortunately). I run it on a remote Windows computer, which I access through Remote Desktop.

PyKeyboard.tap_key() works well while I'm connected, but if I disconnect from the Remote Desktop session, keystrokes are no longer delivered.

Another question: Is disconnecting the remote session equivalent to "Log off->Switch User"? I assume that the problem is that the user is not logged-in (even though a session is running).

Comment: Simpler than that, I made a script to open notepad and type a text. When I'm connected to the VM, the script runs just fine. When I'm not connected (run the script then disconnect from the machine), the script only opens the notepad, but nothing is written

Comment: And by connected I mean logged in. It's a VM that can be accessed via local network only, and requires a password. Don't need to the VM window to be on focus. It works just fine when it's minimized and my actual computer (the one I use to connect to the VM) is actually locked

Comment: Sure, let me post the notepad script

Comment: There it is, on the question

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput/0.1.9

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/install/

Comment: Basically you need to run cmd, go to the folder (where the package is, the setup.py file) and run "setup.py install"

Comment: Sorry about this trouble. I believe it is not a python (nor win32 api for python) issue, but a virtual machine issue. Can you please implement something just as simple in a language you're comfortable with and see if you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64730/discussion-between-sashoalm-and-inox).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not a Python related problem. This happens for `SendInput()` as well (which is probably the WINAPI function Python uses anyway).

From [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b19a1d04-7962-4188-84fd-c52997a0947a/sendinput-to-a-specific-window?forum=winforms):

> Applications are not allowed to send input to the desktop when the computer is locked for security reasons.  I tested changing the cursor position when RDP was minimized, but in fact, the mouse cursor is not shown when the session is restored after being minimized, and when it is restored, no cursor visible until the mouse is moved back over the visible area, in which case it is displayed then where the user moves it.  In fact, even if the RDP window is restored but the mouse on the host machine is not over the window, the mouse cursor in the RDP window will not be visible.  So this is probably not possible either.  If you are trying to achieve a specific behavior, there may be another way to do this other than moving the mouse with simulated input though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure if this is the same issue, as my script works when RDP client is minimized, and even when my actual computer is locked. It only fails when the RDP client is shut down (and no one is connected to the RD)

Comment: Minimizing RDP and locking your own computer does not lock the remote computer - only disconnecting does.