# pykeyboard on remote desktop connection

Tags: python, bots, remote-desktop

i am making a python script for a bot that will click & type on a remote desktop connection
i am using pymouse & pykeyboard modules

this is the code

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
import time


m = PyMouse()
k = PyKeyboard()

k.play_key

m.click(529, 777, 1)
time.sleep(2)
m.click(640, 400, 1)
time.sleep(2)
k.type_string("cctv ins")
m.click(640, 400, 2)
```

On my computer
i tried to make a form to simulate the process it worked fine  i tried it on notepad it worked fine

on the remote desktop
the mouse is working fine but the keyboard isn't

ANY HELP ??????????

Comment: Maybe this gives you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848714/pykeyboard-tap-key-doesnt-work-when-i-disconnect-from-remote-desktop